# Invalid character after object key - What is an object key in geojson?

Tags: json, mongodb, parsing, geojson, mongoimport

I am importing the following text file to geojson:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-122.029517,37.976152]]},"properties":{"name":"thing","origin":"somewhere","end":"blah"}}]}
```

`mongoimport -vvv --db <db> --collection <collection-name> --file <file-name>`

The long verbose output is :

```
<Date, etc> -0700   using 4 decoding workers
<Date, etc> -0700   using 1 insert workers
<Date, etc> -0700   filesize: 921 bytes
<Date, etc> -0700   using fields: 
<Date, etc> -0700   connected to: localhost
<Date, etc> -0700   ns: <db>.<collection>
<Date, etc> -0700   connected to node type: standalone
<Date, etc> -0700   standalone server: setting write concern w to 1
<Date, etc> -0700   using write concern: w='1', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
<Date, etc> -0700   Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character '"' after object key
<Date, etc> -0700   standalone server: setting write concern w to 1
<Date, etc> -0700   using write concern: w='1', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
<Date, etc> -0700   imported 0 documents
```

As you can see, the error is `invalid character '"' after object key`.  The quotes are necessary, however.  Is there an easy fix for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears the third instance of the word `type` is not properly quoted. If you add a double quote prior to that word you should be able to import without any issues.